# Static content in UITableView - Problems with Apples guide

Tags: ios, uitableview, static

I have been following the guide from Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7

concerning: Technique for Static Row Content.

My problem is the following:

All my cells are `nil`.

According to Apple, the loading of the view should instantiate all object populating that nib file, bit only the tableview is instantiated. Thus the cell are nil and crashes the program in method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when it is returning a NULL cell.

I have followed the guide to the letter, search all over and have found no solution, except creating a nib for each cell and loading those ones when needed, but that solution is much less elegant than the Apple solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that as of ios5 / storyboards you can define static content in-place in the storyboard rather than using the technique you link to.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not bound your IBOutlets for the cells to the cells themselves. If your cell ivars are `nil`, then you didn't wire something.

**EDIT**

If the IBOutlets are connected, but the ivars are nil, then the IBOutlets aren't connected. There other possibilities, but that's the most common. Other possibilities: you're trying to access prior to `viewDidLoad`. In particular, you can't access your ivars during `initWithFrame:`. Other possibility is that you're overwriting them at some point. Check their values in `viewDidLoad`. Other possibility is that you're loading the wrong nib file, or not loading a nib file at all. All possibilities, but I'd first check everything in `viewDidLoad` and double-check you're connections.

Comment: The IOButlets are connected to the cells by dragging from Files Owner to the cell.
That is also the reason why i have no clue as to why they are not instantiated.
File's owner is the TableViewController class that has the ivars related to the cells.

Comment: Thank for you time Rob..
I have tested the things you suggested and the results are:
IBOutlets are connected: see image of the connections for File's Owner here ![File's Owner connections](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2250562/connections.png).
The ivars are nil in viewDidLoad.
The ivars are nil in:
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.
I am sure the nib is loading since File's Owner is the TableViewController that controls that nib, and the tableView is NOT nil. I have checked by debugging.

Comment: ViewDidLoad does not contain anything else but [Super viewDidLoad], but that should also be ok, since the instantiation is done thru the loading of the nib file.

Comment: Check your console output. By the time you get to `viewDidLoad`, the IBOutlets should all be bound. If you are not binding your outlets, then you are looking at the wrong object (perhaps not the one that came from the nib file; perhaps you've created one with init?) or you're not connecting to the right things. Loading of top-level nib objects works. It is core to many iOS programs; that part isn't broken.

Comment: OK.. I got it working. Thank you so very much. Even thou i was quite sure the NIB was loaded - it was not. As you said i was looking at the wrong object.  
Solution: add the following code to viewDidLoad:  
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourNibName" owner:self options:nil]  
One last question. Should i also put the same code in viewDidAppear to ensure that the nib is loaded? Thank you very much @Rob

Comment: You have two separate nib files then? This code is very strange. `viewDidLoad` is called after the nib file is read, so you shouldn't load the nib then (unless "YourNibName" is some other nib file perhaps). You certainly shouldn't do this in `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating your table view controller, in your `init` method you should call the overridden designated initializer of the superclass (`[UIViewController initWithNibName:bundle:]`), passing in the nib name:

```
- (id)init {
    return [self initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization here
    }
    return self;
}
```

For more details, see this answer:  [Automatically Loading XIB for UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596336/automatically-loading-xib-for-uitableviewcontroller/2612441#2612441)